# Android: Send info from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

In my MainActivity I have an active search button on my Action Bar/Tool bar/menu. I was wondering if there is a way to filter a list in a Fragment form that active search? Thanks in advance!

It would be even better if each fragment (they are in a viewpager + action bar with tabs) Can have its own action bar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom adapter for your activity's view pager

Then show fragments from adapter, now you have 2 choices for your purpose :

1. define custom toolbar for each fragment in it's own layout (.xml) file and then use it or
2. pass data from activity to fragment adapter and from fragment adapter to your purpose fragment(s) and do filtering.

Good Luck my friend

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to implement using a system service for searching as [described in docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html), then one way of doing it would be as follows:

1. In the onCreate method get a handle to your fragment

   ```
   // if you fragment is embedded with <fragment tag>
   mMySearchFragment = (MySearchfragment)getFragmentManager()
       .findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment) 

   //in case your fragment is added programmatically then, of course,
   getFragmentManager()
   .beginTransaction()
   .add(fragmentid, gragmentinstance, TAG)
   .commit();
   ```
2. In the onCreateOptionsMenu do something like

   ```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_searching, menu);
       mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search_message).getActionView();

       mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {handleSearch(query)}

           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) { ... }
       });

       return true;
   }
   ```
3. And finally

   ```
   private void handleSearch(String query){
       if(mMySearchFragment != null){
           mMySearchFragment.updateSearchResults(query);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Your fragment would need to have a public method `updateSearchResults(String query)` where you would run the search and update your list view's adapter with the new collection

Also, you can import the BasicContactables sample in the Studio (File -> Import Sample) and investigate the code